# Chart.js 2 Bar and line combined chart. Align both y axis at 0

Tags: chart.js2

I'm trying to create a bar and line combined chart. Some of the bars have negative values as seen on the picture, and this create the kind of ugly chart of the picture.

Is there a way to align the 0s of both axis so that the 0s of the line match the 0s of the bars ?

(Note: The 2 y-axis measure different quantities)

[image: The problem]

Comment: Did u find any solution to do that?

Comment: No, I had to live with it. Sorry :-/